# IIF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

Consent:

```
IIf([consents].[decision]=1,"grant",
    IIf([consents].[allowbreaktheglass]=0,"deny""Default"),
    IIf([consents].[AllowBreakTheGlass]=1 AND [consents].[Decision]=0,"emergency only"))
```

`IIF` statement is returning an error:

> The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments

Criteria for consents are Grant, Deny and Emergency only.

Answer (score 3):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to accomplish with your `Nested IIF statement`, however you are simply missing one failure argument, the following may be what you want:

Added 'Error?' for the last failure argument, as well as moved the 'Default' into the failure of the first clause.

```
Consent: 
    IIF([consents].[decision] = 1, 'grant',
        IIF([consents].[allowbreaktheglass] = 0, 'deny',
            IIF([consents].[AllowBreakTheGlass] = 1 AND [consents].[Decision] = 0,
                'emergency only', 'Error?')) 'Default')
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for IIF statement is: `IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )`
You are missing `falsepart` in following 2:

Try Changing: `IIf([consents].[allowbreaktheglass]=0,"deny""Default")`

to: `IIf([consents].[allowbreaktheglass]=0,"deny","Default")`

and: `IIf([consents].[AllowBreakTheGlass]=1 AND [consents].[Decision]=0,"emergency only")`

to: `IIf([consents].[AllowBreakTheGlass]=1 AND [consents].[Decision]=0,"emergency only","")`

for more info visit: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Answer (score 1):

See whether you find `Switch` easier than nested `IIf` statements.

Open a new query in the Access query designer, switch to SQL View, and paste in this statement ...

```sql
SELECT
    Switch(
            c.[decision]=1, 'grant',
            c.[allowbreaktheglass]=0, 'deny',
            c.[AllowBreakTheGlass]=1 AND c.[Decision]=0, 'emergency only',
            True, 'Default'
          ) AS Consent
FROM consents AS c;
```

`Switch` operates on expression/value pairs.  It returns the value from the first pair whose expression evaluates as True, and ignores the remaining pairs regardless of whether or not they would be True.

Not sure I understood the logic for what you wanted, but that first pair would return `'grant'` if `[decision]=1`.  If not, it would examine the next pair.  And so on.  The last pair has `True` as its expression, so when none of the first 3 pairs are matched, the function will return `'Default'`.