# Iff statement in Access report with possible more than 1 true condition

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I want to make a report that could return several conditions. Negative, Positive, Cancelled, Negative/Dilute, or Positive/Dilute. I wrote a IIF statement with several conditions.

```
=IIf([Negative]="1","NEGATIVE RESULT",
    IIf([Positive]="1","POSITIVE RESULT",
       IIf([Cancelled]="1","CANCELLED TEST",
          IIf([Negative]="1" And [Dilute]="1","NEGATIVE/DILUTE RESULT",
              IIf([Positive]=”1” And [Dilute]=”1”, POSITIVE/DILUTE
              )
          )
       )
    )
)
```

The first part, the middle, and the end will all work alone as single statements, but it will not work when all together.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: the last statement misses the else condition, the string delimiters also look strange and there are no string delimiters around "Positive/Dilute". these could be reasons

Comment: Use the Switch function. Example can be found here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846034/iif-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: If Negative = 1 or Positive = 1, the code will never get to the last two conditions. Place those conditions first. And use Switch function. Use quotes around POSITIVE/DILUTE. How did 'smart quotes' get pasted into your code in the last condtion? Access doesn't like them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a mixture of `Switch` and `IIf` functions:

```
=Switch(
  [Negative]="1", "NEGATIVE" & IIf([Dilute]="1", "/DILUTE", "") & " RESULT",
  [Positive]="1", "POSITIVE" & IIf([Dilute]="1", "/DILUTE", "") & " RESULT",
  [Cancelled]="1", "CANCELLED TEST"
)
```